# Lambda Expressions Benefits

Tags: java, lambda

In what Lambda expressions are better than anonymous classes? 
Except making the code less bulky and avoid the confusion about the keyword "this" like in this example:

```
public class TestClass {

   public String variable = "Class Level Variable";


  {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        String variable = "Runnable Class Member";
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("->" + this.variable);
       }
    }).start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    TestClass a = new TestClass();   // prints "Runnable Class Member"
  }
}
```

However in:

```
public class TestClass {

   public String variable = "Class Level Variable";

   {
    Runnable run = ()->{String variable = "Runnable Class Member";
                        System.out.println("->" + this.variable);     
                        };
    new Thread(run).start();
   }



  public static void main(String[] args){
    TestClass a = new TestClass();   // prints "Class Level Member"
  }
}
```

Except this, I cannot see any difference. Do you?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In what lambda expressions are better than anonymous classes

Comment: For one, you don't get one compiled class file per lambda expression; also, the JIT can optimize lambdas once the call site is out of the way, much better than it can anonymous classes.

Comment: Also, they are way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

> Anonymous class: Use it if you need to declare fields or additional methods.
>
> Lambda expression: Use it if you are encapsulating a single unit of behavior that you want to pass to other code. For example, you would use a lambda expression if you want a certain action performed on each element of a collection, when a process is completed, or when a process encounters an error.
> Use it if you need a simple instance of a functional interface and none of the preceding criteria apply (for example, you do not need a constructor, a named type, fields, or additional methods).

Basing on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html you should use lambda expression in case of shorter pieces of code when you do not need class fields. Lambdas are also much easier to read because of higher density of code. Code without lambdas takes many lines to express the basic concept. I think that lambdas are rather syntax sugar than additional functionality.